# Can't create an alias on Cent OS 6.8

Tags: bash, centos, alias, tcsh

In short:

```
$ alias search=grep
$ search
search: Command not found.

$ alias search='grep'
$ search
search: Command not found.

$ alias search="grep"
$ search
search: Command not found.
```

Why isn't `alias` working?

I've also added aliases and run `source` on the following files, but get the same error:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
```

For example, if this is my `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias wtf='git'                                                                 
alias foo="ls"                                                                                  
alias search=grep
```

And I `source ~/.bashrc` and open up a new terminal, I still get this:

```
$ foo
foo: Command not found.
$ wtf
wtf: Command not found.
$ search
search: Command not found.
```

I'm not root on this machine (Cent OS 6.8, not sure if that's relevant), and when I just run `alias` I see the aliases for all users. Can I not create aliases for just my user?

Comment: _Quotes_ as always... `alias search='grep'`. Also, why would you assign such an alias to `grep`? I personally find it confusing/misleading.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html)

Comment: @nikolas That's just a simple example I got from [here](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/create-aliases), and with quotes I have the same problem.

Comment: Might help to put the direct path of grep in your alias (ie `alias search='/bin/grep'`

Comment: @ryekayo, same issue unfortunately. Also, the `grep` thing is just an example, no aliases work. @maulinglawns I don't think it's an issue with my construction, I've used aliases before, it's this machine just isn't taking them for some reason.

Comment: Try using double quotes, then source your .bashrc file

Comment: @ryekayo, Hah, I saw that suggestion coming. Still no change I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you post a copy of your .bashrc file to your question?

Comment: @ryekayo, Sure, there it is. I've tried lots of different combinations of quotes and so on and googled around for previous solutions which were mostly to do with making sure you sourced the files and trying the different files I've included in the question. But for some reason it just won't accept the aliases.

Comment: What is the output of `shopt expand_aliases`?

Comment: Ok and what user are you running this as? and can you provide the full path of your .bashrc on the server?

Comment: @steeldriver, Okay, so I've found the issue from this. When I run `shopt` it in the terminal, it says `shopt: Command not found.` [I looked this up](https://serverfault.com/a/410164/243979) and it's because the terminal isn't actually set to bash. If I run `bash`, then the terminal input changes to `bash-4.1$` then `alias` through the command line and my `.bashrc` works.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the default shell on my machine is [`tsch`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh).

Run `echo $SHELL` to determine what shell you're using. If it's `tsch` or `csh`, then you don't use the `=` sign to assign aliases.

For example, on `tsch`:

```
$ alias foo="ls"
$ foo
foo: Command not found.
```

But:

```
$ alias bar ls
$ bar
<works and lists folder contents>
```

To change your default shell to `bash`, you can run:

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash
```

To keep `tcsh` with aliases, you'll have to create a `~/.tcshrc` file.